# Prop: If $x>0$, then $-x<0$ and vice versa

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Prop:** If $x>0$, then $-x<0$ and vice versa.

**Pf:** Let $F$ be an ordered field. By definition, $x+y<z+y \implies x<z \space \space x,y,z \in F$.

$$x>0 \implies x>x-x \implies x+0>x-x \implies 0>-x$$

and

$$-x<x-x \implies -x+0<x-x \implies 0<x$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking whether your proof is fine. It is, although you could make the uses of commutativity & associativity more explicit. (For example, at one point you use $-x+(x+0)=(-x+x)+0=0+0=0$, with a similar treatment of $-x+(x+x)$.) You can also shorten the proof by proving both directions at once:$$x>0\iff 0<x\iff0-x<x-x\iff -x<0.$$